# How can I replace the values in a matrix of class table?

Tags: r, replace, r-table

In an R object of class `table`, how can I replace its values?

In order to replace its names, I can use:

```
attr( object, "dimnames" )[[1]] <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
```

However, I could not find a way to replace its values! 
How can I create 1 dimensional table (1d)?

`dput` structure:

```
df <-  structure(c(`AL` = 0, `AM` = 2, `AH` = 3), class = "table", .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = list( c("AL", "AM", "AH")) )
```

### More information

The attributes of the original object looks like that

```
attributes( df_object )
$class
[1] "table"

$dim
[1] 3

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
[1] "AL" "AM"  "AH"
```

Current Output

```
AL  AM  AH 
0   2    3
```

The expected output will be: 
Note, it must keep all the attributes that had previously:

```
AL  AM  AH 
10    0    0
```

Comment: The structure you pasted shows as `table [1:3(1d)]` for me, so I don't really get your question

Comment: You can replace a value with standard subsetting operators: e.g `df[1] <- 10`

Comment: @emilliman5 This does not work. It replaces all the names of the df. Lost all its structrure. Try it.

Comment: Julian_Hn I found out that I can create 1d by using array format e.g. `array( df_numbers, dim = c(3), dimnames = list( df_names )  )` However, this lacks the table structure.

Comment: @RonakShah Me expected output is to replace its values, and in the same time to keep its names as well its attributes. I will add more information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subsetting. For example:

```
df[1 : 3] = 4 : 6
df
# AL AM AH
#  4  5  6
```

Comment: Simply and elegant. Thanks. I could not figure it out!